# How to properly make server backup

Tags: linux, backup, ftp, centos7

Since I'm not really a server admin but I'm always eager to learn something new.

I have a dedicated server to take care of. On that server are 2 VMs and on each VM a site (webapp).

Both VMs have CentOS 7 CLI only. I connect through physical server using SSH. When I log there I connect using ssh to any of the VM.

I found a bash script to tar and compress /var/www folder and upload it to a FTP Server. This works OK but the uploaded files are always corrupt. This script makes also an uncompress dump of mysql databases. This file is corrupt too.

So, my question is: Besides fixing what is corrupting the files (the backup itself or the upload or the FTP Server) Is this a good way?? How about the conf files (apache2, mysql, others) Can I simple add them to the backup routine?

I think there are some cleaner & practical tools/scripts to make this. I also try many web admin like webmin, ajenti, centos webpanel. But I don't like using GUI on Server.

**TL;DR:
Need to know if there's a nice way to backup /var/www, mysql dump and other files (such as apache2 and mDB conf) to a FTP, Dropbox, Cloud.**

Thanks for your time. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alright backup method depending on your needs with some pros and cons.

### Pros:

- Easy to create and manage
- No special software needed to view backups
- Can backup everything you need easily

### Cons:

- Potentially lots of files to back up daily
- Large data transfer copying the backups over FTP regularly
  <sup>*</sup>
- Time to restore a crashed system potentially long (re-install server [packages, libraries, users], configure and compile software (e.g. Apache, PHP), restore files to make site function

That said, it is a pretty common method so if you can live with the pros and cons, go with it.<sup>**</sup>

**FTP Corruption Issue**

*My guess is that the FTP files are corrupted because they aren't being uploaded in BINARY mode, and are instead being transferred in ASCII mode.*  Also note, FTP is insecure and your credentials and backups could potentially be intercepted.

**Uncompressed MySQL Dump**

Compress the backup.  It will take longer to backup, but you will probably make up the time in copying.  You can achieve this with a command like:

`mysqldump -u root -pPASS --all-databases | gzip -9 > mysql.sql.gz`

**Backing up other configs**

Yes, you can simply add those to the backup.  If you are backing up `/var/www` now, modify your command to something like this:

`tar cf backup.tar mysql.sql.gz /var/www /etc/apache2/conf* /etc/my.cnf /var/spool/cron /etc/ssh`

The above example backs up /var/www, Apache config directories, the MySQL config file, user crontabs in /var/spool/cron and the SSHD config.  You can add files/directories to the list as needed.

Then after the backups are done, transfer the backup to the remote system and remove it.

Hope that helps!

---

<sup>*</sup>If you can support it or have a remote system you can backup to, look into [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

You can essentially write a command to backup all the files/directories like above except they are securely backed up to a remote system and are also transferred more efficiently.  If you have files that haven't changed between backups, they won't be copied.  If you have a large file (i.e. log file), then only the changed portions are copied thus saving lots of data transfer.

The backup system will need to be accessible over SSH (using keys or password) and have rsync installed.  Then you can manage your backups much more efficiently.  For added security you could then backup the files on the backup server and keep history.

<sup>**</sup> Depending on your host OS, you can look into some block level backup software that can make live backups of your system or VMs that could be used to do a bare-metal restore of the VM.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the answer. I checked the upload script and it was in ascii mode. I'll check how to have a spare VM ready in case of failure. Because if it goes offline I will have to install centos, configure all as you said and that's is not good. Maybe I can backup the whole VM once and then it is just replace the data. Is a good plan? Thanks!

Comment: Having a base image or OS deployment is a good start for the VM machines.  Certainly saves a lot of time in an emergency scenario.  It is unlikely that one of the VMs will fail (but not impossible).  It's more likely the host will fail (hardware/disk failure) or one of the VMs gets hacked in which case its safer to completely do away with it rather than try to clean and fix it as there may still be backdoors or compromised files.  That said, what is your host OS and what virtualization hypervisor are you using?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7 and virt-manger. The host server is provided by iWeb.

Comment: I don't have any experience with it you may also be able to snapshot and backup your VMs as well.  Here are some links: http://relax-and-recover.org/  http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-snapshots-in-Xen-with-Linux-commands http://www.baculasystems.com/products/bare-metal-restore